# How to make a custom print button with SharePoint Designer (2013) that would print the items in a list (not from the browser side)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, 2019

I want to create a custom print button in a list on my SharePoint team site that would print the list in a pretty way, based on the filter or sorting chosen (if any). The Ctrl + P prints from the browser side and gives blank pages, and the format is messed up, my list title would be overlapping the items, etc. I use the modern SharePoint.

Can someone guide me step by step to make a custom button with SharePoint Designer?

I've seen creating a css file and adding it to site assets help, but the steps were very vague. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a print button to SharePoint list items.

**Please follow steps:**

1.Download the print icon:
[image: print.png]

2.Add print.icon to **Site Assets** Library

3.Add a custom action to list

- a) Open your list in SharePoint Designer
- b) Click on **Custom Action** dropdown List, and then select **Display
  Form Ribbon**
  [image]
- c) Name it “Print Item” and set “**Navigate to URL**:” to

  javascript:window.print()
- d) Browse for the **Button image URL (32*32)** and select the **print.png** image you added to Site Assets Library
- e) Change “**Manage**” in Ribbon Location to “**Actions**” and click OK

  Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls._children
  [image]

[image]

Comment: Like I mentioned, this prints from the browser side, which has no alignment when the list is long, and ghosts some data with blank pages.

Comment: Hi, Anugrah. Can you tell me the details of the issue you faced?  Which data is hidden? Or what types of field values are hidden? If you can, please attach screenshots. Have a nice day!